# Why does VMMAP show 128TB of virtual memory address space for any given process on windows 10?

Tags: windows, winapi, x86-64, windows-kernel, virtual-address-space

Windows is supposed to divide the address space such way that there's a split, the low 128 TB is supposed to be for user-space, then after the x86 non-canonical addresses, the higher 128TB is supposed to belong to kernel-space.

I opened VMMAP to take a look at a process virtual memory:
[image]

So apparently it's showing only 128TB of free memory rather than 256TB for all processes, why is that?

Comment: Assume that we somehow consume all 128 TB from user space. Adding 128 TB from kernel space would be missleading, because our process still cannot allocate any additional TB. So free space in kernel space is another kind of free, unusable for user space allocations.